# how to call a model from rabbitmq php consumer's callback in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe

I developed an android app where it subscribes to a queue and also publishes to other queues. At a time it publishes the same message to two different queues, one of them is a queue named "Queue" and now from a appfog instance i need to subscribe to the "Queue" and consume messages and insert them in a mysql db.

I created a php standalone app for the above purpose with codeigniter. By some reason the worker app loses its connection to rabbitmq. i would like to know the best way to do this. How can a worker app on appfog can sustain the application restarts.

what of kind of thing i need to use to solve the above problem.

I figured that the problem is not with rabbitmq connection. it is with the code related to mysql inserts. i checked the crash logs of my app and the error is "Mysql gone away". an example of php rabbitmq consumer has call backs for receive message and register_shutdown. in receive call back i can not use $this of code igniter because its out of scope and i was using get_instance(). i am not sure how to call a method from rabbitmq client receive call back function

The controller is

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
  exit('No direct script access allowed');

include(__DIR__ . '/php-amqplib/config.php');

use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPConnection;

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index() {
    //connect to rabbitmq and consume messages
    //insert messages to mysql
    //$this->messages = array();
    $exchange = "router";
    $queue = "abbiya";

    $conn = new AMQPConnection(HOST, PORT, USER, PASS, VHOST);
    $ch = $conn->channel();

    /*
      name: $queue
      passive: false
      durable: true // the queue will survive server restarts
      exclusive: false // the queue can be accessed in other channels
      auto_delete: false //the queue won't be deleted once the channel is closed.
     */
    $ch->queue_declare($queue, false, true, false, false);

    $ch->queue_bind($queue, $exchange, $queue);

    /*
      queue: Queue from where to get the messages
      consumer_tag: Consumer identifier
      no_local: Don't receive messages published by this consumer.
      no_ack: Tells the server if the consumer will acknowledge the messages.
      exclusive: Request exclusive consumer access, meaning only this consumer can access the queue
      nowait:
      callback: A PHP Callback
     */
    $consumer_tag = "abbiya";

    $ch->basic_recover(true);
    $ch->basic_consume($queue, $consumer_tag, false, false, false, false, function($msg) {
                $message_body = json_decode($msg->body);
                $msg->delivery_info['channel']->
                        basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);

                // Send a message with the string "quit" to cancel the consumer.
                if ($msg->body === 'quit') {
                    $msg->delivery_info['channel']->
                            basic_cancel($msg->delivery_info['consumer_tag']);
                }
                $data = array(
                    'sender_id' => $message_body->r,
                    'receiver_id' => $message_body->s,
                    'message_content' => $message_body->m,
                    // 'sent_time' => $message_body->t,
                    'status' => 0
                );
                $ci =& get_instance();
                $ci->Message_model->newMessage($data);
            }
    );

    // Loop as long as the channel has callbacks registered
    while (count($ch->callbacks)) {
        $ch->wait();
    }

    register_shutdown_function(function() use ($ch, $conn) {
                $ch->close();
                $conn->close();
                $this->index();
            }
    );
}

}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

Answer (score 3):

First off I have to say making a consumer with CodeIgniter and php might not be a great idea unless you add something like this

```
    if( !$this->input->is_cli_request() ){
        show_404(); // So they dont know this is an actual script
        die();
    }
```

and run from the command line with nohup or daemonize it.

You can use codeigniter's $this->db->reconnect(); to reconnect the DB gracefully.

We have made a few consumers for testing purposes with php and CI. 
We put the callback function into a helper and added a way to have the call_back function to return false so the consumer stops listening when we are done.

For our production systems we use either python, java, or camel consumers which are much better suited for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer here since there has been a new library for RabbitMQ on Codeigniter created and available on Github since this question was originally posted

It's very easy to set up and has step by step instructions for doing so in the Readme file: https://github.com/romainrg/rabbitmq_client